# How to map all 64-bit integers to a different 64-bit integer in a 1-to-1 fashion

Tags: c++

The basic form is as such: I want a function with the following signature:

```
unsigned long long getID(unsigned long long index) {
    unsigned long long id;
    /*code involving use of index*/
    return id;
}
```

The id returned needs to adhere to the following constraints:

- There cannot be any collisions (`getID(x) != getID(y)` for any `x` and `y` where `y != x`)
- There shouldn't be any *obviously present* order to the generated numbers (it's okay if there's *some* order, but generally, `getID(x) + 5 != getId(x+5)` for any `x`)
- Every single 64-bit number must be represented by the function. In other words, there cannot be an `id` for which no `x` exists where `getID(x) == id`.

What's the best place to start determining this, and is there a general solution that could be extended to 128-bit (or reduced to 32-bit) numbers without significant changes to the structure of the code?

Comment: How about `return id == 0 ? ULLONG_MAX/2+1 : (id == ULLONG_MAX/2+1 ? 0 : -id);`

Comment: Have you looked at any simple PRNG implementations? Given a seed(index), they output another number (id) in a deterministic fashion.

Comment: Is this for something to do with security?

Comment: There are many encryption algorithms that can work in [small domains](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/subset.pdf) or can provide a 1-to-1 mapping for sets of arbitrary size. Hasty Pudding is definitely one way.

Comment: @twsaef: Collisions bro

Comment: @immibis For all intents and purposes, you can treat the question like it's dealing with security, but rest assured that it's not *actually* being used to encrypt, decrypt, or otherwise manipulate data in the context of protecting it from hacking, as I imagine this kind of system would be exceptionally prone to problems.

Comment: @PreferenceBean if you're claiming that a PRNG must produce collisions, you should look to the now-accepted answer to this very question for a counter-example.

Comment: @twsaef Actually, it's not much of a counter-example. The algorithm that MSalters provided is quite terrible if the goal is a PRNG algorithm. Fortunately, that's not quite my goal.

Comment: @twsaef: Of course not. When did I say that?

Comment: @twsaef: PreferenceBean has a point. Any halfway decent PRNG must be able to produce the sequence `0 0`, which already is a collision. More formally, a PRNG should have a period that is far larger than its range, which by the pigeonhole principle implies that there will be (many) collisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivially, multiplication with any odd prime number works. Use a sufficiently large one (more than 1<<63) to make the pattern less obvious.

Note that if you dislike the predictability, any two answers can be combined. So `x*17 + 5` *also* is an answer.

Comment: This is the answer I like the most; I'm going to run some tests and see if it suits my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could XOR your number with some other fixed number:

```
unsigned long long getID(unsigned long long index) {
    // Replace this with a less predictable number, if you want
    return index ^ 0x123456789ABCDEFULL;
}
```

This has the effect of flipping all the bits in the index that correspond to 1 bits in the fixed number.

It's also its own inverse - `getID(getID(x)) == x`.

It will not completely scramble your numbers, however - indices that are close together will *usually* give IDs that are close together.